# Oracle 11g install on Debian Wheezy does not start

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, installation

I successfully installed Oracle 11g R2 on my laptop for evaluation, by mixing various sources of documentation. I saw the Oracle daemons after installation.
But I have a few problems :

- After a reboot, the instance does not start, and does not even create
  a log file. (only the TNSLSNR starts).
- The oracle user's ORACLE_SID gets a default value (AL32UTF8) where
  the value I set in the /etc/profile.d/oracle.sh initialisation script
  is INFO (created during install). Where does this come from?
- Where can I start investigating?

Thanks for your help.

Note : Only one line not commented out in the /etc/oratab file :

> INFO:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1:N

Best regards,

Fred

Comment: Seems strange that the `ORACLE_SID` is `AL32UTF8` - that is the character set... Is there an `/etc/oratab` file on your system? If so, edit your question with its contents.

Comment: Well, understanding the content of this oratab file, my instance is not supposed to be started ! I modify it in order to allow the database to start ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your `/etc/oratab` file to read:

```
INFO:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1:Y
```

I guess it's just one of those things you need to know to look for!

Comment: Note : ORACLE_SID = AL32UTF8 is a default value set at install by OIU and used in the /home/oracle/.profile file. It was automatically initialised each time I was switching to oracle user typing "su - oracle".